# Sharing CoreData with CloudKit not creating link in production

Tags: swift, core-data, nspersistentcloudkitcontainer

I’ve been able to implement CoreData sharing with other iCloud users, mostly following [Apple’s documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/sharing_core_data_objects_between_icloud_users)

After a lots, of tests I was happy with the result and sent the app to production, but when trying to share a link via iMessage in the release app, the link gets stuck on loading and is never created (see attached picture). I have double-checked and everything in the development CloudKit dashboard has been deployed to production.[image: Screenshot showing the link creation loading forever]

It’s frustrating because it (surprisingly) worked so great in development but I had to remove that feature from the release version because in that environment I can’t make it work.

Any help would be much appreciated.